# Nuances of meaning between "догнать" and "настигнуть/настичь"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Наконец я вас **догнал**.
>
> vs:  Наконец я вас **настиг**.

These two verbs essentially mean "catch up with someone", but I wonder if and how they are nuanced?

Answer (score 3):

**настичь** is purely bookish nowadays, using it in mundane conversations makes one sound altisonant

however unlike **догнать** it also can mean to catch up unintentionally, without chasing after someone, and in this meaning it's synonymous with a more colloquial **нагнать**

for denotation of catching up in figurative sense (catch up to, overtake in knowledge, physical features, accomplishments) **догнать** is currently the only appropriate verb

the difference in register between them reflects in the way i subjectively perceive your examples: in the 1st one **вас** rings *you plural* (German sie), in the 2nd it rings *you singular polite* (German Sie)

Answer (score 2):

"Догнать" is a neutral term and can be used in most situations.
"Настичь" is mostly applicable to the forces of nature - "Нас настигла буря" is still more common than "Нас догнала буря".

"Наконец я вас настиг" sounds like what a villain would say in a comedy (or perhaps anyone with a sense or irony).

Answer (score 2):

1. > Наконец я вас настиг.

   This is absolutely bookish, looks like a citation from a book written in 19th century.
2. > Наконец я вас догнал.

   This phrase looks like an end of the story, which you tell to a person, who you caught up:

   > [A very-very long story about "a chase" ...] ... Наконец я вас догнал.
3. If you want to say this phrase to someone right in the moment when you have caught him/her up, it is better to say:

   > Наконец-то я вас догнал.